# Return None from Enum

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have simple enum:

```
from enum import Enum


class ColorEnum(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        super()._missing_(value)
```

As you can see if None is passed to ColorEnum init it will return None. This works for Python 3.6. But does not work for Python 3.7 when it fails with ValueError:

> ValueError: None is not a valid ColorEnum

For Python 3.6 method `__new__` looks like this:

```
class Enum(metaclass=EnumMeta):
    """Generic enumeration.

    Derive from this class to define new enumerations.

    """
    def __new__(cls, value):
        # all enum instances are actually created during class construction
        # without calling this method; this method is called by the metaclass'
        # __call__ (i.e. Color(3) ), and by pickle
        if type(value) is cls:
            # For lookups like Color(Color.RED)
            return value
        # by-value search for a matching enum member
        # see if it's in the reverse mapping (for hashable values)
        try:
            if value in cls._value2member_map_:
                return cls._value2member_map_[value]
        except TypeError:
            # not there, now do long search -- O(n) behavior
            for member in cls._member_map_.values():
                if member._value_ == value:
                    return member
        # still not found -- try _missing_ hook
        return cls._missing_(value)
```

For Python 3.7:

```
class Enum(metaclass=EnumMeta):
    """Generic enumeration.

    Derive from this class to define new enumerations.

    """
    def __new__(cls, value):
        # all enum instances are actually created during class construction
        # without calling this method; this method is called by the metaclass'
        # __call__ (i.e. Color(3) ), and by pickle
        if type(value) is cls:
            # For lookups like Color(Color.RED)
            return value
        # by-value search for a matching enum member
        # see if it's in the reverse mapping (for hashable values)
        try:
            return cls._value2member_map_[value]
        except KeyError:
            # Not found, no need to do long O(n) search
            pass
        except TypeError:
            # not there, now do long search -- O(n) behavior
            for member in cls._member_map_.values():
                if member._value_ == value:
                    return member
        # still not found -- try _missing_ hook
        try:
            exc = None
            result = cls._missing_(value)
        except Exception as e:
            exc = e
            result = None
        if isinstance(result, cls):
            return result
        else:
            ve_exc = ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
            if result is None and exc is None:
                raise ve_exc
            elif exc is None:
                exc = TypeError(
                        'error in %s._missing_: returned %r instead of None or a valid member'
                        % (cls.__name__, result)
                        )
            exc.__context__ = ve_exc
            raise exc
```

So I would like to get None if None is passed to init. How can I archive that?

Comment: When you instantiate an `Enum`, you'd expect to get an Enum instance back. I.e., `foo = ColorEnum(bar)` ending with `foo` being `None` would be *very surprising behaviour*. You should not expect `ColorEnum(...)` to return `None` ever, you should simply assign `None` to `foo` directly. E.g.: `foo = bar and ColorEnum(bar)` or `try: foo = ColorEnum(bar) except ValueError: foo = None`.